# What is stackoverflow.com.80bola.com?

Tags: discussion, clone

Today I found these websites that are fully similar to the original ones and am curious to know is there any legal connection/interaction between Stack Exchange and these sites or those are some sort of phishing.

- http://stackoverflow.com.80bola.com
- http://academia.stackexchange.com.80bola.com
- http://bicycles.stackexchange.com.80bola.com
- ...

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com.80bola.com/questions/272383/chat-transcript-thinks-i-pinned-a-message-i-didnt) was a result for [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stack+overflow+meta+starred+pinned&oq=stack+overflow+meta+starred+pinned&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i65j0l2j69i64.3344j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) on Google. Not good!

Comment: Seems [80bola](http://stackoverflow.com.80bola.com/) has stopped working!

Comment: Yay :D​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ..Although it now redirects to a chinese shopping site.

Comment: Currently it is redirecting to AliExpress, I thought it might be only on my browser or computer, but it is also redirecting to that site even usinga proxy (tried using rxproxy.com) and VPN, it might also redirect to another sites.

Comment: And now it's been replaced by www.searchalleasy.com. Sigh.

Comment: @Shadow It's not a clone site. Per the answer, it's a proxy site. (I didn't add the [tag:proxy] tag due to its tag wiki.)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog tricky, hard to tell without digging into it.

Comment: The sits appear to be no longer online, closing this as no-longer- reproducable

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is a (slow) *proxy site*; it accepts **any** domain name in front of `80bola.com`:

- http://slashdot.com.80bola.com/
- http://cia.gov.80bola.com/

or links from your profile:

- http://abforce.ir.80bola.com/pages/goldoon.html
- http://ir.linkedin.com.80bola.com/pub/ali-reza-barkhordari/82/7a8/a87

etc.

In other words, they are not specifically copying Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I just visited a proxied question on page 2 of Googling "django rotating file handler". I wouldnt have even noticed it. Seems like no-good behavior.

Comment: damn..and they pollute Google searches

Comment: @Juri: yes, because they proxy *everything* and rewrite all links, they are a page rank network all of their own. I expect Google to cotton on eventually and simply remove the network from the index.

Comment: Perhaps we can move that along a bit somehow. I just got caught by this and shared an 80bola link without realising.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: There is [this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Pw1KVOVRyr4a7ezj_6SHghnX1Y6bp1SOVmy60QjkF0Y/viewform) but I think it is up to Stack Exchange to report it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I concur; I guess I meant to prod SE into action with my comment :P

Answer (score 27):

Although it's only a proxy site, I would definitely not recommend using it, as there are **possible** vulnerabilities (feel free to edit or add to the list):

1. **[Cross Sub-domain Scripting](http://mattsnider.com/cross-subdomain-scripting/)** - although sub-domains are considered different and will not pass the Same Origin Policy unless the `document.domain` is tampered with, different browsers still behave differently
2. **[Cookies might be 'shared'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139/1140227)** - if explicitly named in the Set-Cookie header. Currently the login sessions are separate. i.e. logining in stackoverflow does not log you in stackoverflow.com.80bola.com
3. **[Cross Frame Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Frame_Scripting)** - Although unlikely, it is still possible for 80bola to use 2 frames to exploit a cross-frame-scripting bug to access private data on a third-party website
4. **[Man-in-the-middle](http://www.trusteer.com/glossary/man-in-the-middle-mitm)** - Depending on how the proxy is set up, there's a possiblility that traffic is visible to 80bola and of intercepting and manipulating the packets.

*Adding a screenshot here for future reference in case the proxy is removed:*

[image]

Lastly, I believe all the content and backlinks are giving them additional SEO juice to push them up the search ranking.

Comment: The domain is registered this year through a company called WHOISGUARD, INC in Panama.  Just by surfing to www.80bola.com it will redirect you through google short-urls and jump to some adsite (godaddy.com). Its fishy!

Comment: @Exterior8931509 Whoisguard is just a replacement as registrar if the domain buyer wants to remain anonymous. It's a common thing for phishing sites.