# Phishing sites (proxies) to most common Stack Network sites

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, jobs, search-engine, clone

A similar problem was already reported here: [What is stackoverflow.com.80bola.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250916/what-is-stackoverflow-com-80bola-com), but it does not answers my question.

I want to know what us as a community need to do to block this kind of sites stealing the network traffic.
In the answer to the linked question they don't give any steps on what the community should do, where to report it ?, do the mods have more weight when reporting to Google (I did fill in a report, but who knows when a Google bot will read it), do we have any other tools that can help ?

The network in question is **wwwblogher.com** and their sub-domains:

- stackoverflow.wwwblogher.com
- careersstackoverflow.wwwblogher.com
- ...

*Unfortunately lately they get more weight on my Google searches then the original Stack network.*

Comment: Can you give me the search phrases you used where you saw them outrank us in results?

Comment: @Tim https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=gettext+jed+multiple+domains&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=gettext+jed+multiple+domains&channel=fs&start=0, the last result in the first page redirects to the general newest question with "gettext" tag on their proxy.

Comment: Also, just a warning @all that some of the ads on wwwblogher.com are NSFW ads.

Comment: @Quill So sorry, I should have warned you guys, AdBlock did not block any (I had to manually hide them with Element Hiding Helper). That is one of the reason I was so pissed of by the ripoff, as I could just end up open-it it by mistake with my 5y son near me.

Comment: I think network traffic isn't really a big deal for this particular proxy with the pornographic ads, because most people aren't in a situation where that's appropriate, and would close it, opting for vanilla, but if they had no header and no ads, then there'd be a bigger problem.

Comment: A tool *we* could use also, is reporting the domain to the domain register, because *depending* on the host, they might take it down.

Comment: Checking with some folks to see what we can do about it, hang tight.

Comment: Blocked by firefox as "Reported Web Forgery!

This web page at stackoverflow.wwwblogher.com has been reported as a web forgery and has been blocked based on your security preferences. Web forgeries are designed to trick you into revealing personal or financial information by imitating sources you may trust.

Entering any information on this web page may result in identity theft or other fraud."

Comment: Sorry about the bump, I was under the impression a retag wouldn't cause it. I'll have to read the bump FAQ again more carefully.

Comment: The sub-sites appear to no longer be active, and the main site is full of NSFW ADs and images.