# What exactly is 80bola?

Tags: discussion

I was browsing through Google until I clicked on a StackOverflow site such as this without noticing the 80bola domain:

stackoverflow.com.80bola.com

Then, I was immediately redirected to this page: https://stackexchange.com/about/malware?host=stackoverflow.com.80bola.com

I searched to see what 80bola is and ended up learning that it's a proxy from here:

[What is stackoverflow.com.80bola.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250916/what-is-stackoverflow-com-80bola-com)

[Stack Overflow hacked? Got redirected to stackoverflow.com.80bola.com on login](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290490/stackoverflow-hacked-got-redirected-to-stackoverflow-com-80bola-com-on-login)

So, my understanding of proxy is it's like a VPN that masks your IP address when visiting websites. But I still don't understand if my computer has been infected with some sort of malware or phishing. Is my computer safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

80bola.com in particular is a site unblocker, or at least that's how it advertises itself. It lets users enter in any domain and it automatically serves as a proxy of the content. Their server fetches the content of the page, and then resends that information back to the user to bypass blocks that the user might be experiencing. While not all proxies are malicious in nature, it's always a possibility when you let someone else process *every single thing* you do with a website before it goes to the server or the result comes back to you. When using such a service, you should consider your security level and privacy to be zero.

Since this site serves as a proxy of the exact some content available on our site, sometimes the content it serves ends up in Google search results. This proxy is one of those services that *very frequently* pops up in Google. Not everyone always pays attention to the domain they're visiting when they click on things in Google, and they don't notice that while the page *looks* exactly like Stack Overflow, they're *not on* Stack Overflow. Because this site is not affiliated with us, we don't know what they actually do with the requests they proxy, and it poses a serious security threat to our users who unwittingly use their service. So, we started implementing ways of detecting and blocking such proxy services and redirecting them back to us in order to protect our users.

**It's unlikely that you have any malware on your computer.** It's worth mentioning, though, that there are much more malicious proxy services out there. We have run across some that not only proxy our content like this service does, but also inject ads and malware on top of that content which *can* cause serious harm to your computer if you're not careful. If you're at all concerned, you can always run virus and/or malware scans on your computer to make sure it is clean.

Comment: Thank you for this! Thank you, thank you! I thought I was already being extremely careful when browsing websites. Heh, my caution in web browsing has risen to the next stage...